# How to forget remote folder user credentials?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-2012

I couldn't create a VHD disk on a remote share (`\\ortak\backup\lucasrv`) because I supplied the wrong credentials, and saved them in the Remote File Browser dialog box.

I can create VHD disks at `\\ortak2\backup\lucasrv`, the test location.

How can I reset saved user credentials? I think the information is stored in Hyper-V Server 2012 because I've tried to add a disk from a different Hyper-V Manager with no luck. Resetting the user credentials in Hyper-V Manager won't help.

[image]

Comment: Two options: (1) In the start menu search for "manage passwords" and take a look at the various saved Windows Credentials.  (2) from a command line `net use` to list and `net use \\server\share$ /delete` to delete one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

net use \\sharename /delete won't work until you log off. You must log off.

Answer (score 0):

At the command prompt, issue the command `net use` and validate that no active connections are open to the server.

If not, issue the command:

```
net use * /delete
```

then attempt to re-connect. You should be prompted for credentials again.

Comment: I can browse, create, delete the share resources. Hyper-V cannot. Plus there are no related Net Use results at both Windows 10 & Hyper-V 2012.

Comment: Adding anonymous access rights resolved the problem. With zero security.

Comment: Domain joined both ?